# Por que me llego esta notificación en los logros?

Tags: discusión

Me parece un poco extraño que me haya llegado esta notificación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estaba creando [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/497371/33391) y entre ediciones vi un voto negativo, al momento siguiente recibo esta notificación y el voto desaparece, aunque la notificación persiste. Es alguna nueva funcionalidad?

Comment: La notificación sale cuando un usuario votó en tu pregunta o respuesta, pero al ser eliminado se revierten los puntos asignados [aquí más información](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed).

Comment: Al parecer se hizo limpieza, yo también tengo un descuento de puntos por usuario eliminado.

Comment: No es una nueva funcionalidad jeje, ya me pasó algunas veces. ;)

Comment: Muy interesante, gracias por la info.

Comment: Alce la mano el-que-tiene-un-usuario eliminado (8) alce la mano !!!

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [900 puntos por usuario eliminado](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5303/900-puntos-por-usuario-eliminado)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sacado de 
[¿Por qué tengo un cambio de reputación en mi página de reputación que dice 'Se quitó el usuario'?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed)

> Este mensaje significa que la cuenta de un usuario que votó por una o
> más de tus publicaciones ha sido borrada (a petición suya o por
> incumplir los términos de uso de la red). Como resultado, todos sus
> votos se anularon, y la reputación que ganaste o perdiste por los
> susodichos fue anulada. El resultado del cambio de reputación puede
> ser cualquier cantidad; podría incluso ser una ganancia si la
> suficiente cantidad de los votos anulados eran negativos. Todos los
> cambios de reputación resultantes del borrado del mismo usuario se
> agrupan en una única anotación en la página de reputación con la
> etiqueta "Se quitó el usuario".
>
> Esta rectificación ocurre siempre que un usuario es borrado, excepto
> si el usuario tenía mucha reputación. Dado que los usuarios con una
> reputación alta normalmente ya han emitido muchos votos, anularlos
> todos podría ser un trastorno para otros usuarios. En estos casos el
> equipo usa un borrado especial que preserva los votos, siendo el
> resultado que no hay cambios de reputación para aquellos que han
> recibido votos de ese usuario.

Comment: Acaba de [publicar](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5303/900-puntos-por-usuario-eliminado) un usuario que le quitaron 900 puntos de reputación, Para mí eso sería casi la mitad de mi reputación. ¿Si me hubiera pasado a mí se podría llegar a apelar esa decisión de borrar los votos?

Comment: Podría dar para que se debata, pero hasta donde entiendo es algo esperado. Si un usuario MUY activo, como el que se elimino o eliminaron, se borra, no habrá rastro público de èl. Tampoco es el primer usuario activo que veo que se va,

Answer (score 3):

Es un comportamiento normal del sitio, cuando un usuario votó por tu publicaciones y su cuenta fue eliminada sucede esta situación.

[¿Por qué tengo un cambio de reputación en mi página de reputación que dice 'Se quitó el usuario'?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed)

> Este mensaje significa que la cuenta de un usuario que votó por una o
> más de tus publicaciones ha sido borrada (a petición suya o por
> incumplir los términos de uso de la red).

de hecho en otras ocasiones ha sucedido lo mismo a otros usuarios, en este caso desgraciadamente fueron varios usuarios los que fueron afectados, por ejemplo [eferion](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/463/eferion) publicaba la misma [situación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5303/900-puntos-por-usuario-eliminado).

Este es mi caso:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo interesante aquí es también conocer por qué un usuario que probablemente llevaba tiempo en el sitio tuvo la decisión de eliminar su cuenta.

Comment: Me parece un comportamiento un poco extraño. En mi opinión, no es necesario eliminar todo el contenido de un usuario, solo lo que lo relacione a él de manera directa, pero su participación? Algo drástico.

Comment: No se elimina el contenido que haya realizado, pero si su reputaciòn y votos.

Comment: Bueno, siendo de esa manera, creo que no es tan drástico.