# 900 puntos por usuario eliminado

Tags: soporte, reputación

Esta tarde me ha llegado un regalito en forma de 900 puntos de reputación menos por un usuario eliminado.

Tenía entendido que cuando se eliminaba un usuario y sus aportaciones habían sido importantes no se eliminaban sus votos.

Que a mi en el fondo tener 900 puntos arriba o abajo no me va a cambiar la vida, pero imagino que ese usuario habrá emitido otros tantos votos a otras personas que habrán sido igualmente eliminados... y algunos de esos votos pueden hacer que gente con menos puntos pierdan privilegios de repente.

¿Es este el comportamiento esperado en este portal? ¿Dónde estaría el límite?

Comment: Es correcto, el comportamiento es el esperado. Lamentablemente, el usuario o fue eliminado, o eliminó su cuenta. Si es así, cada parte está en su derecho de hacerlo. El tema igual se estaba discutiendo acá: [Por que me llego esta notificación en los logros?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5300)

Comment: Igual da como para discutirlo en META como menciona otro usuario, dado que 900 puntos tampoco es que sea poca cantidad.

Comment: Un regalo similar al mio! :.<

Comment: Es un número interesante, en mi caso el regalo fue bastante más barato.

Comment: que raro.. yo no perdi puntos... quiero averiguar que paso.. son muchos puntos para mucha gente...

Comment: les menti.. perdi 150....

Comment: Y alvaro perdio mas que vos...

Comment: @gbianchi por eso digo, creo que el usuario eliminado aportó demasiados votos como para eliminarlos de un plumazo

Comment: Relacionado: [Pérdida de puntos por usuario eliminado](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1308/pérdida-de-puntos-por-usuario-eliminado)

Comment: No perdí ningún punto. No deber haber sido usuario Python.

Comment: Creo tener una idea de quien fue... más que extrañar los puntos extrañaré a este usuario.

Comment: Yo perdi 10 ptos, esta vez, otras veces he perdido un poco mas y realmente es algo q molesta, nadie tiene la culpa de las meteduras de pata de otro usuario, yo pienso q lo q te ganaste bien ganado aunque sea 0,001 pto nadie te lo debe quitar, sancionen al usuario q cometio fraude y borren todas sus cuentas, denuncienlo en la ONU, pero los ptos no se deben perder

Comment: Para mi, que recien puedo cerrar y abrir preguntas luego de 2 años en esta comunidad, 900 puntos es un montón :c

Answer (score 9, accepted):

La razón por la que los puntos se perdieron es porque el usuario eliminado tenía historial de [sock puppets](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuenta_de_usuario_t%C3%ADtere) en su pasado.

Hablé con el community team, y a futuro van a analizar la fecha en el que el usuario a eliminar hizo sock puppeting, pero hoy en día se pierden los votos de un usuario eliminado si está comprobado que hizo sock puppeting.

Comment: Irrespectivamente a si sus votos fueron hacia sus otros socks o no?

Comment: correcto, al eliminar un usuario con muchos votos. Si hizo sock puppetting -> todos los votos emitidos se eliminan

Comment: ¡Gracias! Y crees que sería posible, en teoria al menos, limitarlo y solo quitar votos hacia los socks? Imagino que sí es posible no será simple, ya que es difícil encontrar todos los socks, pero quizás al menos no quitar votos hacia usuarios que por cierto _no_ son sus socks?

Comment: jejeje... en teoría es posible si...

Comment: A futuro puede ser 5 años

Comment: eso es perfectamente cierto :)

Answer (score 3):

Pido disculpas a todos los afectados, era curiosidad para ver qué pasaba si borraba la cuenta, ya estoy denuevo.

---

Sobre el Sock Puppet, es verdad, pero solo fue una cuenta, la de AutoReplicante, no recuerdo el nick exacto que tuve. Fue hace mucho tiempo.

---

Copio y pego el correo, si el correo indica lo correcto, la cuenta fue borrada por la aprobación de un desarrollador.

Tiene partes no traducidas aún:

> **Your Stack Overflow en español profile has been scheduled for deletion**
>
> Hola,
>
> We recently received your request to delete your Stack Overflow en español profile and it is currently scheduled for deletion.
>
> We're sorry to see you go. If you change your mind or didn't request the deletion, you can cancel this request by logging into **your profile** and clicking the banner shown there.
>
> Debido a tu reputación y/o número de votos, la eliminación requerirá la aprobación final de un desarrollador luego de 24 horas. Una vez aprobado, su perfil será eliminado inmediatamente - no necesita solicitar la eliminación de nuevo.
>
> Si necesitas algo más, visita nuestro **formulario de contacto** y selecciona 'Otro' para obtener ayuda adicional.
>
> Gracias.
> El equipo de Stack Exchange

La parte no traducida diría lo siguiente:

> **El perfil de Stack Overflow en español ha sido programado para la eliminación**
>
> Recientemente recibimos tu solicitud para eliminar el perfil de desbloqueo Stack Overflow en español y actualmente está programado para la eliminación.
>
> Sentimos verte partir. Si cambias de opinión o no solicitaste la eliminación, puedes cancelar esta solicitud iniciando sesión en **tu perfil** y cliqueando en el banner que se muestra allí.

Alternativamente, en el correo, si el usuario no tiene la cantidad de votos importante, se cambia lo siguiente:

> Debido a tu reputación y/o número de votos, la eliminación requerirá la aprobación final de un desarrollador luego de 24 horas. Una vez aprobado, su perfil será eliminado inmediatamente - no necesita solicitar la eliminación de nuevo.

Por este nuevo párrafo:

> De lo contrario tu perfil será eliminado en las siguientes 24 horas.

Comment: Claro, art... pero si hubieras preguntado y leido que pasaba, lo hubieras sabido sin probar. Desgraciadamente, todos los puntos se perdieron... la proxima vez, pregunta ;)

Comment: @gbianchi Me imagino que si llego a volver a borrar la cuenta se perderían otra vez los puntos, porque el historial de sockpuppet todavía está.

Comment: Los puntos no se han recuperado, parece ser algo permanente

Comment: @eferion Parece que sí es permanente, se tendría que contactar el gestor de comunidad y debatirlo, no veo otra manera... Al borrar mi cuenta no recibí ningún correo en relación a esto.

Comment: Pues nada, me debes 900 puntos de nada. Luego te paso mi numero para que me hagas una transferencia XDD

Comment: @eferion Lo acepto... Corrección, no recibí más correo que el automático, que tenía 24 horas para cancelarlo.

Comment: hay unas cuantas cadenas para traducir ahí :)

Comment: @g3rv4 En traducir.win me apareció este error: `Error: Error: Script error for "strings/strings"
https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
Source File: https://static2.traducir.win/lib/require.2.3.6.min.js?v=SUjD_ktXzZIRjse4neuZ_w6yWGoCxfRU3yHB7PwUTIE Line: 5`

Comment: @ArtEze en qué url? usando qué navegador?

Comment: @g3rv4 Firefox Light 48.0, tendría que usar otro navegador, pero a mi computadora le cuesta mucho, tengo una RAM de 960 MB... Sobre la URL, en la principal https://es.traducir.win/ al buscar scheduled... Directamente no me funciona el sitio.

Comment: Hola Emiliano, bienvenido de nuevo, como siempre curioseando con las herramientas del sitio, si fueras moderador ya hubieras eliminado a todos los usuarios del sitio para ver qué pasaba, es broma haha!. Como comenta g3rv4 la próxima vez pregunta! Bienvenido al sitio nuevamente!

Comment: @Elenasys Bueno, preguntaré la próxima... Debe haber algún mecanismo ya implementado para evitar el borrado masivo de usuarios, lo desconozco.

Answer (score 2):

Desde mi punto de vista creo que sí se debe adoptar un sistema más estricto al momento de remover o conservar los votos de un usuario eliminado. El autor de la pregunta dice que 900 puntos no le afectan tanto, sin embargo, tal vez para algunos sea frustrante por todo el trabajo que tuvieron que realizar para ganar 900 puntos (que no son poca cosa).

En mi caso 900 puntos sería casi la mitad de mi reputación y el perderlos sería un golpe terrible, más allá de los privilegios que me otorgan esos puntos vendría por la confianza hacia el sitio. ¿Qué me asegura que de un día a otro no voy a perder los puntos obtenidos con esfuerzo?

**Para mí el error clave sería en** el artículo que explica este proceso, el cual nos dice:

> Esta rectificación ocurre siempre que un usuario es borrado, excepto si el usuario tenía mucha reputación. Dado que los usuarios con una reputación alta normalmente ya han emitido muchos votos, anularlos todos podría ser un trastorno para otros usuarios.

Sin embargo, yo he visto a usuarios que tienen varios años aquí y tienen poca reputación y esto no implica que no sean activos o no hayan tenido un impacto en la comunidad (como la emisión de votos acumulados a través de años que no otorgan reputación al usuario)

### ¿Qué podríamos hacer?

#### Primer punto

Considerar si el usuario fue eliminado por incumplir los términos de uso de la red.

Creo que este es el paso más importante para la comunidad, porque un usuario que va en contra de las reglas del sitio:

1. Normalmente no es un usuario que lleve demasiado tiempo en el sitio, por lo que probablemente no afecte demasiado eliminarlo
2. Si va en contra de los términos de uso, probablemente sus votos tampoco sean hechos de manera consciente, por lo que eliminarlos podría ser beneficioso para el sitio

#### Segundo punto

Considerar cuántos puntos serían revertidos si se eliminaran sus votos.

Más allá de si el usuario tenía mucha o poca reputación, se debería de evaluar el impacto que tendría, como expresé anteriormente, creo que el sistema para evitar el borrado de votos está al revés, pues considera qué tanto le afecta al usuario ser borrado, no qué tanto le afecta a la comunidad que ese usuario sea borrado.

**Y se debería de establecer un límite**

El artículo nos menciona que:

> El resultado del cambio de reputación puede ser cualquier cantidad

¿Qué pasó en este caso?

No se estableció un límite y varios usuarios perdieron mucha reputación, si a mí me hubiera tocado perder 300 puntos de reputación creo que me hubiera enfadado con el sitio, perder 900 puntos habría hecho que dejara de participar en esta comunidad al menos por un buen rato. Sin embargo, para mí no sería correcto evaluar un sólo caso, pues el *serial-voting* hacia un usuario podría impedir que se eliminaran los votos, por ello se debería de ver de manera colectiva con medidas de tendencia central o incluso con un modelo estadístico

Comment: Cuando digo que 900 puntos no cambian nada en mi caso es por dos razones: no participo aquí por la reputación y mis privilegios no se ven afectados. Obviamente prefiero tener mis 900 puntos y todos los demás que consiga, ya que eso quiere decir que mis aportes siguen siendo útiles, pero a lo que voy es a que en mi día a día esa pérdida no cambia nada

Comment: Estamos averiguando que paso. La perdida de puntos fue masiva e incluso hubo varios usuarios que perdieron mas de 900 puntos...

Comment: A mi la interfaz me notifica la pérdida de 738 puntos ñ_ñ

Comment: En general, la catidad de votos perdidos es proporcional a los puntos que tengas. Si tienes 1000 puntos sería muy sospechoso que 600 vinieran de un único usuario. Los usuarios que perdimos cientos de puntos en general no nos vamos a ver afectados.

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo único que tengo que reprochar es que perdí sólo 40 puntos. ¿En serio @Arteze? ¿Tan pocos votos me habías dado? ¿Después de tantos años conociéndonos en el chat y en el sitio en general?

Siempre que recibía un upvote, por dentro decía: *seguro fue Arteze, él siempre tan bueno dándome votos positivos*.

Ahora, aparte de la decepción, lo que me queda es la esperanza que mi fan sea otro usuario, y sospecho de @Pikoh, y a veces hasta de @gbianchi. Sé que me tienen presente en sus upvote, sobre todo cuando se trata de J y JS.

Comment: Pobrechito, desilusionado y traicionado por su buen "fan" xDDD ...... Espera, en serio estàs desilucionado???

Answer (score 0):

Yo perdí 50 puntos solamente pero recién había llegado a los 3000 puntos con esto acabo de perder el privilegio de participar en la cola de cierre... 50 puntos que si me costaron ya que soy relativamente nuevo en cuanto a participación ...

Me parece que esto no es para nada justo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: A mi me pasó algo similar cuando llegué a los 2000 XD, ahora solo perdí 20 creo porque no estoy respondiendo ya muy seguido XD, pero veo que de verdad hay muchos usuarios afectados.